# OpenID Connect - UserInfo endpoint Redundant?

Tags: microservices, openid

Why would we use the  [userinfo](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo) endpoint in OpenID Connect to get information about the user when we can simply include that information in the access token?

> The UserInfo Endpoint is an OAuth 2.0 Protected Resource that returns Claims about the authenticated End-User. To obtain the requested Claims about the End-User, the Client makes a request to the UserInfo Endpoint using an Access Token obtained through OpenID Connect Authentication. These Claims are normally represented by a JSON object that contains a collection of name and value pairs for the Claims.

If my services were to call the userinfo endpoint this would increase coupling and is a potential failover.

If the information can be included in the token then doesn't this make the userinfo endpoint redundant?

Comment: because openid is a bloody pain in the arse. I think there are some login methods where you dont get an access token?

Comment: Access tokens can also be simple random strings, and relying on them for encoding information also has some downsides. That said, I don’t see why you would need the endpoint if you use information-carrying tokens to their full extent.